# Menu bar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

[image: Menu bar]

Can someone tell me what element from the toolbox builds this kind of menu? And I guess I can "skin" it, right? I mean, the background image etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is toolstrip control. I don't think there is a direct support for changing skins. You may require some third party libraries. Yes you can change the background image.

Comment: Thanks, third party libraries huh... I'll search bit about that :)